# Почему метод Contains для LinkedList<T> выдает False (C#)

Tags: c#, linked-list

```
class checkin
{
    public string first;
    public string second;
    public checkin( string f,string s)
    {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<checkin> check = new LinkedList<checkin>();
        check.AddLast(new checkin("One", "Two"));
        checkin t = new checkin("One", "Two");
        Console.WriteLine(check.Contains(t));
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что по факту в список ты добавляешь не сам экземпляр класса, а ссылку на объект в памяти. И потому, когда ты создаёшь новый экземпляр класса в `checkin t`, то t хранит ссылку на экземпляр класса отличный от того, что в списке.

Comment: А почему он должен выдавать что то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, что немножко протупил, забыв переопределить метод Equals (object obj). После этого все заработало.

Comment: переопределяя Equals, не забудьте переопределить и GetHashCode, особенно если класс будет использоваться как ключ